# Homeoffice VPN: torrent filenames visible at company?

Tags: vpn

I use VPN to connect to my company. Can they see the filenames which are downloaded on torrent?

Comment: VPN software *should* only process requests directed at your company's local intranet, everything else will take the normal route.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, that is only true if split tunneling is enabled and working correctly. otherwise all traffic will pass through the VPN gateway, and to the Internet at large from there. Op, Encrypt your torrent connections. then they will be able to see who your peers are, and potentially that it is a series of bittorrent connections, but won't be able to see the contents.

Answer (score 1):

MonkeyZeus is probably right. Your employer probably doesn't want all your internet traffic passing through their infrastructure. But I wouldn't bet my job on it.

To determine the answer to your question you will need to examine your routing table. Your routing table is a set of rules to determine how your computer send network traffic based on its destination IP address. First connect to your VPN and run `ipconfig /all` and make note of the IP addresses of the IP addresses of your network adapters and your VPN adapter. Next, run `route print` from the command line. There are countless resources describing in detail how to read the routing table but in a nutshell you want to find the combination of Network Destination and Netmask that most closely matches the IP address you are communicating with (your torrent peers). More specific matches take precedence over broader ones (ie. longer netmask always wins). In the event of a tie, the one with the lowest Metric value is used. Then, examine the Interface column and compare to the IP addresses of your network adapters for a match. That is the adapter that is handling the traffic. The good news is you probably only have one or two rules that match any public IP addresses at all (most will be for private or multicast addresses). In fact, there's a good chance you have exactly one such rule for a Network Destination of 0.0.0.0 and a Netmask of 0.0.0.0.

If you determine that traffic to the IP addresses of your torrent peers is leaving your computer through your VPN interface, it is indeed passing through your company's network. If it's leaving via your physical network adapter then they will never see it.